# Type mismatch. VARCHAR and TIMESTAMP with Pheonix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

Getting Error:

```
ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. VARCHAR and TIMESTAMP for '2017-08-30 06:21:46.732'
SQLState:  22005
ErrorCode: 203
```

while executing the below query in SQuirrel SQL Client with apache.pheonix

```
select * from USER_T where USR_CRT=cast('2017-08-30 06:21:46.732' AS timestamp)
```

and USR_CRT type is TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

Wich version of Phoenix are you using?

With the function [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#to_timestamp) works like a charm for me. Your query will be:

`select * from USER_T where USR_CRT = TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-30 06:21:46.732')`

I'm using Phoenix 4.11.0 with HBase 1.3.1 and Hadoop 2.7.3 over AWS EMR